# Select from Table until certain value is found

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so:

```
+--------+---------------------+------------+
| id     | timestamp           | value      |
+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 566076 | 2013-10-17 11:16:38 | 1          | -> get these
| 565989 | 2013-10-17 11:15:27 | 1          | ->
| 565881 | 2013-10-17 11:14:17 | 1          | ->
| 565860 | 2013-10-17 11:14:10 | 1          | ->
| 565869 | 2013-10-17 11:14:09 | 0          |
| 565869 | 2013-10-17 11:14:08 | 0          |
| 565869 | 2013-10-17 11:14:07 | 0          |
| 565869 | 2013-10-17 11:14:06 | 1          |
```

How can I select all records, that have a `timestamp` that is larger than the largest `timestamp` that is associated with a `value` of `0`?

Comment: how about writing procedure to do this

Comment: Why not this SELECT id, timestamp, value FROM table WHERE value = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC or SELECT id, timestamp, value FROM table WHERE value != 0 ORDER BY timestamp DESC ? of do i misunderstand you? and make sure you have an index on (value, timestamp) or you need un filesort..

Comment: *until* makes no sense in relation to database tables. The records in a database table are not inherently ordered. Any order must be specified by the database programmer explicitly (and by extension, your question should say something about which order is desired).

Comment: Why should `565869, 2013-10-17 11:14:16, 1` not be included in the result set? By which method of comparison does it come after `565869, 2013-10-17 11:14:19, 0`?

Comment: Still your question doesn't make sense can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Oswald They are sorted by timestamp DESC, and they represent dates for other queries where columns are to be selected between the first and last timestamp in this query.

Comment: @ErikSoderstrom Then why is `565860, 2013-10-17 11:14:10, 1` included? It has a lower timestamp than `565869, 2013-10-17 11:14:16, 1` which is not included.

Comment: @Oswald Sorry, when I edited my question i wrote wrong. Re-edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends of what are you meaning 'value hits 0'. There's no 'an order' in terms of SQL, only 'the order by certain column'. And with that could you easily resolve your issue with

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE `value`='1' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

-here order column is `timestamp`, descending order (from your sample). Probably, you'll also want to add `LIMIT` to your rows. May be, also, you want to find everything before first zero with certain order, then:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  t 
WHERE 
  value=1
  AND
  timestamp>(SELECT timestamp FROM t WHERE `value`='0' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

-but yet again - it's possible to do this when you've specified certain order.

Comment: YEs exactly, I want to find every column, ordered by timestamp, until first zero is found. I'll try your example out.

Comment: @ErikSoderstrom - well, that depends of your `timestamp` order (`asc` or `desc`)

Comment: if you order on timestamp you should get id's 565860, 565869 and 565881 what is incorrect with the id's in the start post 566076, 565989, 565881 and 565860..

Comment: But that's the point. There's no 'just order'. There's order by column - i.e. if we'll set order by timestamp - of course, id could be shuffled.

Comment: indeed question needs be elaborated more

Comment: @RaymondNijland Done that; based on the comments of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, that yo may find easier to understand.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM t 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS MaxtimeStamp
    FROM t 
    WHERE `value`='0'
) sub1
ON t.timestamp > Sub1.MaxtimeStamp
```

Comment: I've delayed going into joins, but it seems inevitable. Thanks for your answer, I'll try it out.